# Parsing JSON with retrofit-gson?

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

I am trying to work with retrofit to parse the json data but there is no data received help me to parse the data.

Below is the builder and interface i created :

```
public class fetchdata {
    private static UserFetchData userdatafetch = null;

    public static UserFetchData getService() {
        if (userdatafetch==null) {
            String url = "the_instagram_link";
            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(url)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();

            userdatafetch = retrofit.create(UserFetchData.class);
        }
        return userdatafetch;
    }

    public interface UserFetchData {
        @GET("full_name")
        Call<User> getFullName();
    }
}
```

Below is `jsonschema2pojo` files to be used in app :

```
-----------------------------------com.google.app.HdProfilePicUrlInfo.java-----------------------------------

package com.google.app;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class HdProfilePicUrlInfo {

@SerializedName("height")
@Expose
private Integer height;
@SerializedName("url")
@Expose
private String url;
@SerializedName("width")
@Expose
private Integer width;

public Integer getHeight() {
return height;
}

public void setHeight(Integer height) {
this.height = height;
}

public String getUrl() {
return url;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
this.url = url;
}

public Integer getWidth() {
return width;
}

public void setWidth(Integer width) {
this.width = width;
}

}
-----------------------------------com.google.app.User.java-----------------------------------

package com.google.app;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class User {

@SerializedName("is_verified")
@Expose
private Boolean isVerified;
@SerializedName("biography")
@Expose
private String biography;
@SerializedName("follower_count")
@Expose
private Integer followerCount;
@SerializedName("media_count")
@Expose
private Integer mediaCount;
@SerializedName("hd_profile_pic_url_info")
@Expose
private HdProfilePicUrlInfo hdProfilePicUrlInfo;
@SerializedName("external_lynx_url")
@Expose
private String externalLynxUrl;
@SerializedName("following_count")
@Expose
private Integer followingCount;

public Boolean getIsVerified() {
return isVerified;
}

public void setIsVerified(Boolean isVerified) {
this.isVerified = isVerified;
}

public String getBiography() {
return biography;
}

public void setBiography(String biography) {
this.biography = biography;
}

public Integer getFollowerCount() {
return followerCount;
}

public void setFollowerCount(Integer followerCount) {
this.followerCount = followerCount;
}

public Integer getMediaCount() {
return mediaCount;
}

public void setMediaCount(Integer mediaCount) {
this.mediaCount = mediaCount;
}

public HdProfilePicUrlInfo getHdProfilePicUrlInfo() {
return hdProfilePicUrlInfo;
}

public void setHdProfilePicUrlInfo(HdProfilePicUrlInfo hdProfilePicUrlInfo) {
this.hdProfilePicUrlInfo = hdProfilePicUrlInfo;
}

public String getExternalLynxUrl() {
return externalLynxUrl;
}

public void setExternalLynxUrl(String externalLynxUrl) {
this.externalLynxUrl = externalLynxUrl;
}

public Integer getFollowingCount() {
return followingCount;
}

public void setFollowingCount(Integer followingCount) {
this.followingCount = followingCount;
}

}
-----------------------------------com.google.app.Userdata.java-----------------------------------

package com.google.app;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Userdata {

@SerializedName("user")
@Expose
private User user;

public User getUser() {
return user;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
this.user = user;
}

}
```

and this is how i tried to get the data :

```
public void GetData {
        Call<User> jsondata = fetchdata.getService().getFullName();
        jsondata.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
                User user = response.body();
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Yeeeeep !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();//added the break point but no data recived but it toasted
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }
```

Glide dependencies :

`implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'`

`implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'`

I really don't know what i am doing wrong and how to solve it.
I really want to know how to parse the json.

Thank you.

**EDIT**
This is the responce i will recieve from the server :

```
{
  "user": {
    "external_lynx_url": "https://l.instagram.com/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%2F\u0026e=ATPCIx1ldIEQpnqvlYYf-W9bvjDwTqw4XGRSCjt5mr5VhqwlaEsaHpdkMUiU2BfQumhKNM3IJEQri5UX8Qsz8p2G",
    "username": "google",
    "has_anonymous_profile_picture": false,
    "external_url": "http://google.com/",
    "full_name": "Google",
    "profile_pic_id": "1825015012270132630_1067259270",
    "media_count": 830,
    "pk": 1067259270,
    "hd_profile_pic_versions": [
      {
        "height": 320,
        "url": "https://instagram.fjai1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/1df66b7b71efa2a6dba025f38a47495a/5BE04111/t51.2885-19/s320x320/36616551_641374529567850_6798278096731504640_n.jpg",
        "width": 320
      },
      {
        "height": 640,
        "url": "https://instagram.fjai1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/e453300e2a8170426349c370afe2c8f7/5BD45B7E/t51.2885-19/s640x640/36616551_641374529567850_6798278096731504640_n.jpg",
        "width": 640
      }
    ],
    "is_private": false,
    "is_verified": true,
    "reel_auto_archive": "on",
    "biography": "Google unfiltered\u2014sometimes with filters.",
    "follower_count": 7035887,
    "has_highlight_reels": true,
    "usertags_count": 311,
    "following_count": 12,
    "profile_pic_url": "https://instagram.fjai1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/e4e4a1a1c41950738442218cf892669e/5C0D19E1/t51.2885-19/s150x150/36616551_641374529567850_6798278096731504640_n.jpg",
    "hd_profile_pic_url_info": {
      "height": 1080,
      "url": "https://instagram.fjai1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/10891608f8e9f072ac5dcb4e9554b7a6/5BE33A1B/t51.2885-19/36616551_641374529567850_6798278096731504640_n.jpg",
      "width": 1080
    },
    "auto_expand_chaining": false
  },
  "status": "ok"
}
```

Comment: post your json response.  Use DTO generator  plugin of android studio instead of  jsonschema2pojo

Comment: add `HttpLoggingInterceptor` to retrofit for detail logs https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor

Comment: hiii @SaurabhBhandari I've posted the response which i will be receiving from the server. Hope this led you to help me.

Comment: hii @prashant17 i'll be more glad if you could help me with the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your retrofit client method will be as follows

```
public static UserFetchData getService() {
        if (userdatafetch==null) {
            String url = "https://i.instagram.com/";  //this ur base url
            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(url)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();

            userdatafetch = retrofit.create(UserFetchData.class);
        }
        return userdatafetch;
    }
```

Your User Pojo Model Will be as follows :

```
public class UserModel {

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("status")
    public String status;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("user")
    public User user;

    public String getStatus() {
       return status;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    } 

    public static class User {
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("auto_expand_chaining")
        public boolean auto_expand_chaining;
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("hd_profile_pic_url_info")
        public Hd_profile_pic_url_info hd_profile_pic_url_info;
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("profile_pic_url")
        public String profile_pic_url;
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("following_count")
        public int following_count;
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("usertags_count")
        public int usertags_count;
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("has_highlight_reels")
        public boolean has_highlight_reels;
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("follower_count")
        public int follower_count;
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("biography")
        public String biography;
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("reel_auto_archive")
        public String reel_auto_archive;
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("is_verified")
        public boolean is_verified;
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("is_private")
        public boolean is_private;
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("hd_profile_pic_versions")
        public List<Hd_profile_pic_versions> hd_profile_pic_versions;
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("pk")
        public int pk;
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("media_count")
        public int media_count;
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("profile_pic_id")
        public String profile_pic_id;
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("full_name")
        public String full_name;
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("external_url")
        public String external_url;
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("has_anonymous_profile_picture")
        public boolean has_anonymous_profile_picture;
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("username")
        public String username;
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("external_lynx_url")
        public String external_lynx_url;
    }

    public static class Hd_profile_pic_url_info {
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("width")
        public int width;
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("url")
        public String url;
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("height")
        public int height;
    }

    public static class Hd_profile_pic_versions {
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("width")
        public int width;
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("url")
        public String url;
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("height")
        public int height;
    }


}
```

Your retrofit `interface` like as follows

```
public interface UserFetchData {
        @GET("/api/v1/users/2055338526/info")  //here is your api end points
        Call<UserModel> getFullName();
    }
```

In your `getData()` Method will be as follows :-

```
public void GetData {
        Call<UserModel> jsondata = fetchdata.getService().getFullName();
        jsondata.enqueue(new Callback<UserModel>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<UserModel> call, Response<UserModel> response) {
                User user = response.body().getUser();
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Yeeeeep !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();//added the break point but no data recived but it toasted
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<UserModel> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: hii @SaurabhBhandari i tried your code but there is null pointer exception. see here https://justpaste.it/5ani0

Comment: you can check you are hitting correct api using   before hitting the service `Log.d("URl",fetchdata.getService().request().url())`

Comment: I did that but i think the problem was in the GetData() code. See You'are calling Call<UserModel.User> instead i Called <UserModel> and UserMode.User at responce.body i changed it and it worked !

Comment: but i am still confused dude :| for example i need to get only name then what to do ? Edit :: It didn't worked for me Errors Everywhere for me

Comment: thats so simple just use `user.full_name` after getting it or you can get  as `response.body().getUser().full_name`.

Comment: Okay so i got the dumb human bug :| there is no getter and setter in usermodel and i was trying to get the names.

Comment: yes i told you prefer getters. if you dont use them it will directly show you variable list

Comment: Thank You Very Much Brother For you guidance  ! and of course i will accept the answer.  :) Edit: Voted and accepted the answer :)

Comment: @wiils happy coding . Use DTO genrator plugin of Android studio for creating pojo

Comment: can you please help me with this one. I am trying to get the input that user is doing on the edittext but when i put that value it says `Attribute must be const` here is the code please take a look.  https://justpaste.it/6vi8k

Comment: @wiils follow this tutorial https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-basics-of-api-description

Comment: Please take a look at my beggn question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51519857/null-pointer-exception-retrofit

Comment: @wiils first hit url and creat pojo of response

Comment: Thanks buddy but already solved the shit. Asking another question please be there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51522437/correct-way-to-hide-and-show-widgets please see here.