# Parsing String Arrays in JSON with Retrofit

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit2, pojo

**For moderator: It's not duplicate question, because in other quiestions there are DIFFERENT format of JSON-responce!
In my case, proposed approaches don't useful, unfortunatly :(**

For example, in first case - I haven't string of responce (because i use gson), and in second I have error when I try to use `List<String>` (Unable to create converter for `java.util.List<java.lang.String>`) :(

---

I have a JSON-answer in such format (with many string arrays):

```
{
"marketdata": {
 "columns": [
  "SECID",
  "BID",
  "OFFER",
  "SPREAD",
  "LCURRENTPRICE",
  "UPDATETIME",
  "TIME",
  "SYSTIME"
],
"data": [
  [
    "AFLT",
    121.4,
    121.5,
    0.1,
    121.5,
    "12:25:45",
    "12:25:34",
    "2018-07-25 12:40:45"
  ],
  [
    "KRKNP",
    11400,
    11430,
    30,
    11400,
    "12:25:00",
    "12:16:12",
    "2018-07-25 12:40:00"
  ],
  [
    "LKOH",
    4347,
    4349.5,
    2.5,
    4349.5,
    "12:25:46",
    "12:25:40",
    "2018-07-25 12:40:46"
  ]
 ]
 }
}
```

I created simple pojo file (https://pastebin.com/PQvnQCRb) and it's doesn't work even for "columns" field. And, of course, I need to parse "data" fields too... Where is my mistakes? Thanks.

Comment: Take String [] instead of List<String> in class Marketdata

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51503557/parsing-json-with-retrofit-gson/51504477#51504477

Comment: **Bhoomit_BB**, it's gave the same error