# Correct way to hide and show widgets?

Tags: android, android-studio, widget

In my app, I need to show and hide widgets like `button` and `textview` at a certain time.
and how I am doing is as the following:

```
private void hideviews() {
    image.setVisibility(View.GONE); ///ImageView
    title1.setVisibility(View.GONE);///TextView
    title2.setVisibility(View.GONE);///TextView
    title3.setVisibility(View.GONE);///TextView
    title4.setVisibility(View.GONE);///TextView
    title5.setVisibility(View.GONE);///TextView
}

private void showviews() {
    image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    title1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);///TextView
    title2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);///TextView
    title3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);///TextView
    title4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);///TextView
    title5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);///TextView

}
```

I don't think this is the correct way to do this. 
Because I don't know how many widgets there will be.
Any guidance on how to correctly show widgets is really appreciated.

Comment: Be more specific, what are you trying to achive?

Comment: My Layout which have these widgets but on creation of the activity they should be not visible so i call the `hideview` on for example button click i need them to be shown and the code i wrote is not sufficient for the work there should be certified way to do the same which i don't know'

Comment: @wiils your are already using simple and best approach.  you can go with it

Comment: yeah i see but may be not the beset

Answer (score 1):

Get the reference to root layout, iterate through the childs, check if the view at certain index is instance of EditText(or View that you dont need to hide), if not hide it

```
RelativeLayout root = findViewById(R.id.root)
for(i=0,i<root.getChildCount()-1,i++){
    if(! (root.getChildAt(i) instance of EditText)){
       root.getChildAt(i).setVisibility(View.GONE)
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't know how many testviews will be attached, then I believe that the best approach will be to:

- get the reference of the parent view group (that contains all the
  textviews),
- loop through all the childs using `getChildAt`,
- verify whether the object is an instance of TextView/ImageView and if so set its visibility according to your logic

Comment: i was looking for code examples, they will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hiding every widget separately hide the root layout.

```
RelativeLayout rootLayout;

rootLayout= (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.root_layout);
```

and use something like this to control the visibility.

```
public void setLayoutInvisible() {
    if (rootLayout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
        rootLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
public void setLayoutVisible() {
    if (rootLayout.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
        rootLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hii @WahabKhanJadon but i like to set Visibilty of some widgets like EditText while hiding the other widgets on the same layout.

Answer (score 0):

Make an array of all the views that you want to show/hide:

```
View[] views = {image, title1, title2, title3, title4, title5};
```

and then use this to hide them:

```
for (View view : views) {
    view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

and use this to show them:

```
    for (View view : views) {
        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

although you can combine the 2 code parts in a single procedure:

```
void fixViews(int state) {
        for (View view : views) {
            view.setVisibility(state);
        }
}
```

and call it:

`fixViews(View.GONE);` or `fixViews(View.VISIBLE);`